# AngularJS, Nested array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem with `ng-repeat` in AngularJs. I have an array of Objects with 3 different keys and one of those keys is an array of objects. So I simply use the `ng-repeat` for main array like this:

```
<div class="post-content" ng-repeat="post in nfc.posts track by $index">
  ...
</div>
```

Everything is ok. But when I use a nested `ng-repeat` in this loop, I get nothing. I used before nested `ng-repeat`s a lot and faced no problem. Here is the code:

```
comments:: {{post.comments}}
<div class="post-comment" ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
  comment: {{comment}}
  <img src="{{comment[3]}}" alt="" class="profile-photo-sm" />
  <p>
    <a href="" class="profile-link">{{comment[4] + ' ' + comment[5]}}</a> {{comment[6]}}
  </p>
</div>
```

The `comments:: {{post.comments}}` statement shows me the content, but the `ng-repeat` does not appear to work correctly.

A sample of `comments` object in browser console is here

```
Array(3)
0: {
    0: 10196,
    1: 10325,
    2: 62,
    3: 0,
    4: Sun Feb 18 2018 21: 56: 58 GMT + 0330(+0330),
    5: "text", 
    6: "text",
    7: "text",
    8: "text",
    9: "text",
    $$hashKey: "object:96"
  }
1: {
    0: 10195,
    1: 10325,
    2: 50,
    3: 0,
    4: Sun Feb 18 2018 20: 15: 41 GMT + 0330(+0330),
    5: "text", 
    6: "text",
    7: "text",
    8: "text",
    9: "text",
    $$hashKey: "object:97"
  }
2: {
    0: 10194,
    1: 10325,
    2: 62,
    3: 0,
    4: Sat Feb 17 2018 12: 36: 39 GMT + 0330(+0330),
    5: "text", 
    6: "text",
    7: "text",
    8: "text",
    9: "text",
    $$hashKey: "object:98"
  }
```

This array is **Array of arrays** and I convert it to **Array of objects** after I receive it from API.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: There is nowhere totoObject(array) function in your controller and even you are not importing it from anywhere.  Is it by mistake?

Comment: Yeah, That's a typing mistake @ImranAhmadGhazali

Comment: Did you get the bug ?

Comment: Unfortunately no!@ShashankVivek

Comment: can you post what you get when you do console.log(JSON.stringify(nfc.posts));

Comment: paste here and share the url https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: provide a valid json, no need to give entire json. just 2 object should be fine to reproduce your issue. the above link is not a valid json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170966/discussion-between-saeed-ataee-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue ? What was the cause

Comment: Thanks for asking. I add some loadings to pages and this code with no change worked! I think it is something about lifecycle and digest in angularJs. But still I dont know the reason. @ShashankVivek

Comment: `loadings` ? Do you mean spinners or something else  ?

Comment: Yes, I mean that! @ShashankVivek

Answer (score 4):

First mistake I noticed in your code is this **totoObject**(itm["arrays"]))

```
  $scope.posts.forEach(itm => (itm["comments"] = totoObject(itm["arrays"])));
```

your code that you provided in plunker says

```
 function toObject(arr) {
    var rv = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) rv[i] = arr[i];
    return rv;
  }
```

change **totoObject** to **toObject**

`$scope.posts.forEach(itm => (itm["comments"] = toObject(itm["arrays"])));`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<img src="{{comment['3']}}" alt="" class="profile-photo-sm" />
```

`comment[3]` means that **comment** is an array and you are trying to access **4th** element. Similarly change other uses as well.

#### Update 1

[Check this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2wkCQfy0KabzXyDlIldi?p=preview). Below were your issues:

1. Use of `totoObject`
2. In your question you have provided array of objects (below code), which isn't the case in your plunkr. So, `comment[3]` would work just fine.

here (it shows array of objects)

```
 0: {
    0: 10196,
    1: 10325,
    2: 62,
    3: 0,
    4: Sun Feb 18 2018 21: 56: 58 GMT + 0330(+0330),
    5: "text", 
    6: "text",
    7: "text",
    8: "text",
    9: "text",
    $$hashKey: "object:96"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But `comment: {{comment}}` must show something before that. right?

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee can you create a plunkr with the Json data ? The answer i provided will also help once you are able to see **{{comment}}**

Comment: Make this plunkr work please https://plnkr.co/edit/n8oh66zfOxuhcRSjM5dY?p=preview

Comment: That totoObject is a typing mistake, I,ll Copy my whole code here https://plnkr.co/edit/ZCUm0C78gOv7SZbtlBCr?p=preview

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee Have you checked your plunkr ? You havent included `script.js` file , you havent added <html> and `<body>` tags. The IIFE file is incomplete.  If thats the script then change `angular.module("app.user")` to `angular.module("app.user",[])`. Also there is no `ng-app`. Create a complete example 1st plz and let me know

Comment: Look, it is a small part of my whole project. It works fine. But this part does not work correctly. I just copy all code of this part, because I think my problem is not programatically and is something about angularJs logic and lifecyles!

Comment: Can you share screenshot of `console`. I cant help unless I have a complete code (even if it doesnt work). with 1500+ reputation, I hope you can understand :( .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170855/discussion-between-shashank-vivek-and-saeed-ataee).

Answer (score 2):

Check the demo,

**DEMO**

```js
var app =angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.nfc ={};
   $scope.nfc.posts = [
  {
    "Post": {
      "Name": "text",
      "Family": "text",
      "UserName": "text",
      "WorkPlace": "text",
      "UserImage": "~/Images/User/Thumb1337305170mmkhalilzadeh2018294642.jpg",
      "PPic": "~/Images/Post/1337305170502018211044.jpg",
      "DSC": "text",
      "CF": "text",
      "CN": "(Mediastinum)",
      "Rate": 0,
      "MentionPostID": 0,
      "FollowCount": 1,
      "UserID": 50,
      "Enable": 1,
      "UPID": 10325,
      "IsFollow": false,
      "IsRate": false,
      "IsFollowUser": true,
      "RegDate": "2018-02-10T21:30:44.000Z"
    },
    "PostComment": [
      [
        10196,
        10325,
        62,
        0,
        "2018-02-18T18:26:58.000Z",
        "text",
        "~/Images/User/Thumb1337305170Shahryar201711122149.jpg",
        "text",
        "text",
        "text"
      ],
      [
        10195,
        10325,
        50,
        0,
        "2018-02-18T16:45:41.000Z",
        "text",
        "~/Images/User/Thumb1337305170mmkhalilzadeh2018294642.jpg",
        "text",
        "text",
        "text"
      ],
      [
        10194,
        10325,
        62,
        0,
        "2018-02-17T09:06:39.000Z",
        "text",
        "~/Images/User/Thumb1337305170Shahryar201711122149.jpg",
        "text",
        "text",
        "text"
      ]
    ],
    "newCommentText": "",
    "comments": [
      {
        "0": 10196,
        "1": 10325,
        "2": 62,
        "3": 0,
        "4": "2018-02-18T18:26:58.000Z",
        "5": "text",
        "6": "~/Images/User/Thumb1337305170Shahryar201711122149.jpg",
        "7": "text",
        "8": "text",
        "9": "text"
      },
      {
        "0": 10195,
        "1": 10325,
        "2": 50,
        "3": 0,
        "4": "2018-02-18T16:45:41.000Z",
        "5": "text",
        "6": "~/Images/User/Thumb1337305170mmkhalilzadeh2018294642.jpg",
        "7": "text",
        "8": "text",
        "9": "text"
      },
      {
        "0": 10194,
        "1": 10325,
        "2": 62,
        "3": 0,
        "4": "2018-02-17T09:06:39.000Z",
        "5": "text",
        "6": "~/Images/User/Thumb1337305170Shahryar201711122149.jpg",
        "7": "ttt",
        "8": "ttt",
        "9": "ttt"
      }
    ]
  }
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<div class="post-content" ng-repeat="post in nfc.posts track by $index">
 <div class="post-comment" ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
  <img src="{{comment[3]}}" alt="" class="profile-photo-sm" />
  <p>
    <a href="" class="profile-link">{{comment[4] + ' ' + comment[5]}}</a> {{comment[6]}}
  </p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```